# Programmatically fill Adobe PDF Forms (AcroForms)

Tags: vb.net, forms, pdf, acrobat

I have an application, that copies a `PDF form` (with control elements like `textboxes`) and lets the user fill and save it (without ever printing it). There are a few `fields like "name", "first name"`, day of birth and so on, that my application knows itself so I'd like to `make my application fill these fields on its own`, to save the user some time.

Is there an interface for vb.net, that allows me to write into PDF-Textboxes?

Answer (score 0):

You will need a PDF library for this. I would recommend you to try [Docotic.Pdf library](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/) for the task (I work for the vendor).

Please take a look at the sample that shows how to [fill existing PDF form](https://github.com/BitMiracle/Docotic.Pdf.Samples/tree/master/Samples/Forms%20and%20Annotations/FillForm).

Comment: If I got that right your library is not an official interface, but a chargeable one. Since the price is way to expensive for that little use I have for it I'll be looking for something else.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need a PDF library for AcroForms in a PDF.

Simply just Acrobat Reader (rewriter) will do. What you do need to do is export the textual data from VBA in a Form Data File (FDF is much like mail merging).

Then either double click the autoload FDF to open Adobe (Acrobat) Reader to in turn fill the PDF, OR use an FDF toolkit to fill thousands of files in sequence from any database such as Excel. However simpler is use Reader Print **/T**o.

You have an Template form.pdf for usage in Adobe reader.

[image]
[image]

**You export your forms textual data PER PDF in this format** (this part you need your VBA programming skills for) HomerSimpson.FDF

```
%FDF-1.4
%Form
1 0 obj
<<
/FDF <<
/F (HomerSimpson.pdf)
/Fields [<<
/T (Dobby) /V (5/12/72)
>> <<
/T (FirstName) /V (Homer)
>> <<
/T (LastName) /V (Simpson)
>> <<
/T (MiddleName) /V (Jay)
>>]
/UF (Template.pdf)
>>
/Type /Catalog
>>
endobj
trailer
<<
/Root 1 0 R
>>
%%EOF
```

Then double click that file will auto fill the template.
Or **auto-print to PDF or paper.**
**ONE command line per user.**
`"C:\Program Files\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\acrord32.exe" /T printing options HomerSimpson.FDF`

Here I have not set auto print but manual print (/P) to illustrate what happens simply, when call the FDF with a print command.

[image]